# update value of an object in an array - react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to increment the counter value of an item on click, I've tried to find the solution in the docs and I watched tutorials but I can't find the solution.

FruitCounter.js

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react"
import Fruit from "./Fruit"

const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "", counter: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: "", counter: 0 },
]

const FruitCounter = () => {
    const [fruits, setFruits] = useState(data)

    const clickHandler = (fruit) => {
       // Increment 'counter value of clicked item by 1'
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {fruits.map((fruit) => {
                return (
                    <Fruit
                        key={fruit.id}
                        {...fruit}
                        clickHandler={() => clickHandler(fruit)}
                    />
                )
            })}
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default FruitCounter
```

Fruit.js

```
import React from "react"

const Fruit = ({ counter, name, clickHandler }) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" className="fruit" onClick={clickHandler}>
            <p>{counter}</p>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
        </button>
    )
}

export default Fruit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
  const clickHandler = (fruit) => {
    setFruits(
      fruits.map((x) => {
        if (x.id === fruit.id)
          return {
            ...x,
            counter: x.counter + 1,
          };
        return x;
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: As [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous): `setFruits((prevFruits) =>
    prevFruits.map....`.

Comment: @AjeetShah In general you are right, but inside click handler, when you don't have multiple setState calls, most of the times you will always read fresh state anyway.